# Lance Game Engine pong tutorial gets syntax error

Tags: lance

In the Lance Game Engine when I try to run their pong tutorial I type:

```
sudo yarn start
```

I get this error:

```
/var/nodes/lancegame/node_modules/lance-gg/src/ClientEngine.js:125
    connect(options = {}) {
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

uninstalled lance-gg and ran `npm install lance-gg@1.0.1` (older version) as instructed in the slack forum and now things work.